# How to get the value from each field of a class with Byte Buddy?

Tags: byte-buddy, javaagents

I'm writing a library that uses Java Agents with Byte Buddy to perform runtime code generation. I need to create an expression to get the value from each field of a class.

How can I create an expression to access the field value? Currently I'm exploring the `FieldDescription`API but I not found anything to do this.

Comment: What kind of instrumentation are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I have another question. How can I get the `TypeDescription` for the class to be generated into a `MethodDelegation.to(AddFooMethod.class)`?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter I just need to create a method inside a class annotated with a specific annotation

For example:

    `@MyAnnotation public class Person {
        private String name;
        private String email;

        // method to be generated
        public void generatedMethod() {
            System.out.println("name " + this.name + " email " + this.email);
        }
    }`

Basically I want to generate a method inside a class that access all fields to get its value.

Answer (score 0):

From the additional information, you provided on GitHub, this is how you would approach this:

To create a `StringBuilder` you call `MethodCall.construct(StringBuilder.class.getConstructor())`

You can then call the append to the string builder like: `MethodCall.invoke(StringBuilder.class.getMethod("append", Object.class)).onMethodCall(...).withField(...)` where you start with the initial string builder and then reiterate for every field or constant supplying the last input to the next instance.

You would have to adjust the method based on the field type, if the type is primitive, for this to work. In the end, you have to do a final method call on `toString`.