# How to transfer data to/from method argument to self in Bytebuddy?

Tags: byte-buddy

I have a base class

```
public abstract class Cache {
    public abstract void load(Object input);
    public abstract void dump(Object output);
}
```

Would like to subclass it in Bytebuddy and

1. define a certain number of fields (This I am able to do)
2. implement to 2 abstract methods:

- for load, get value from its fields and set the corresponding field (of the same name) in the Cache object
- for dump, get value from the Cache object and dump it into object

Tried `FieldAccessor` but seems the API isn't suited for this purpose? Couldn't find any solution online except for this ancient answer which is supposedly addressed but I can't find the corresponding code [How to get the value from each field of a class with Byte Buddy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771241/how-to-get-the-value-from-each-field-of-a-class-with-byte-buddy)

---

Example

```
public class Input {
   double foo;
   String bar;
}
public class Output {
   boolean z;
}
```

Based on this supplied classes (Input & Output), extend/implement a Cache class with bytebuddy such that it does the following

```
public class ByteBuddyCache extends Cache {

    double foo;
    String bar;
    boolean z;

    public void load(Object input) {
        Input i = (Input) input;
        this.foo = i.foo;
        this.bar = i.bar;
    }
    public void dump(Object output) {
        Output o = (Output) output;
        o.z = this.z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of a class you try to create?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter added~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require you to create custom `StackManipulation`s. In these, you would combine `FieldAccess` objects and `MethodVariableAccess`.